# OpenVPN: failed to resume on wake up

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I've installed an OpenVPN daemon on my Ubuntu 13.04 computer, I'm forwarding all my traffic through a personal server. Everything works fine, I've also installed it with success on several other machines.

The problem I have is that the OpenVPN daemon fails to restart every time my computer wakes up from a sleeping state (not on start-up). The solution I found is to restart the daemon by hand (`service openvpn restart`), which works fine but I want to find a more elegant solution.

A `dmesg -l err` gives me the following output:

```
[ 4735.041739] dpm_run_callback(): pnp_bus_resume+0x0/0x80 returns -19
[ 4735.041741] PM: Device 00:07 failed to resume: error -19
```

I already looked for a solution but I didn't find anything. The problem doesn't appear on other computers. Is there anything I could do or is it tied to my computer?

Comment: It's not a solution, just workaround, but you may use `acpi-support` package and `STOP_SERVICES="openvpn"` in `/etc/default/acpi-support`. To stop openvpn before suspend and restart after resume.

Comment: @week I tried this but I get the same issue and the same error output with a `dmesg -l err`

Comment: Did you identify what device 00:07 is?

Comment: @week How can I do that?

Comment: Run `lspci` and find device 00:07.

Comment: `07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)` It's my ethernet controller (not a lot of surprises there). Let me look for similar problems with this particular device.